# Color scan problem with HP LaserJet MFP on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, scanner, hplip, sane, laserjet

My system is:

- HP LaserJet MFP m236dw
- Ubuntu 18.04
- HPLIP ver. 3.21.8

hp-scan gives gray picture up to 300 dpi with no problems.
However, in color mode "hp-scan -m color" it gives the following error:

> Warming up...
> Scanning...
> error: SANE: Error during device I/O (code=9)
> Closing device.

Doesn't matter if USB or Network connection.
I've tried all solutions I could find on the Internet.
I tried several HPLIP versions with complete cleanup&reinstall and at some point it gave me 300 dpi color picture, but after reboot it stopped working again and I failed to reproduce the conditions that caused it to work once.
hp-check and hp-doctor see no problems.

Printing works OK.
Any help is appreciated....

Comment: Did you run `hp-plugin` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I've just noticed an interesting thing. It scans in color if percentage of white below some level relatively to scan area size. If I try to scan A4 with small pencil drawing it returns an error and if I add some more scribbles and try to scan drawing again then it works. if I scan business card and scan size is set to "full" in xsane it doesn't work, but when reduced to 13x18cm then it's OK. If I try to scan some a4 picture or a document it works fine again, but if it's just almost clean a4 it gives the same error. gray scan always works OK.